# Visualize a large number of eigenvectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, eigenvector

I have 6 matrices for which I am required to plot the **eigenvectors**. These matrices have dimensions from 20x20 to 320x320. I really do not know what would be the best (clearer) way to **plot** them. Is there any library available to your knowledge? I thought about reducing the dimension of each eigenvector but still, it would be a lot of work.

```
N = [40, 80, 160]; % Dimension 1-D grid

% Laplace operators
L1 = -1/((1/N(1))^2) * full( ( spdiags(repmat([1,-2,1], N(1)-1, 1), -1:1, N(1)-1, N(1)-1) ) );
L2 = -1/((1/N(2))^2) * full( ( spdiags(repmat([1,-2,1], N(2)-1, 1), -1:1, N(2)-1, N(2)-1) ) );
L3 = -1/((1/N(3))^2) * full( ( spdiags(repmat([1,-2,1], N(3)-1, 1), -1:1, N(3)-1, N(3)-1) ) );
```

These matrices are the Laplace operators associated to Poisson's equation. The aim is to visualize how the eigenvectors change when we change the dimension of the 1D grid I use to solve Poisson's equation.

Comment: What is the purpose of plotting the eigenvectors?  Knowing what you want to show (or not show) with the plot will help guide you in selecting a method.

Comment: You might find high dimensional data visualization techniques useful: [like these](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-visualize-high-dimensional-data) or [these](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56589/visualizing-high-dimensional-data).

Answer (score 2):

As you have intuited, we cannot plot them the same way we would plot a 3D vector. If you want to visualize the spacial distance between eigenvectors, you could consider geometry preserving dimensionally reduction like [isomap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomap), but the simplest visualization, is to plot the dimensions of the eigenvectors.

First, let's get some eigenvectors. I use the same example as the [`eig` documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eig.html)

```
A = gallery('lehmer',20)
[A_eig_vec, A_eig_val] = eig(A);
```

Then plot each column as a line. I also use multiple plots to avoid the plots getting too noisy with too many lines.

```
subplot(4, 1, 1);
plot(A_eig_vec(:, 1:5));

subplot(4, 1, 2);
plot(A_eig_vec(:, 6:10));

subplot(4, 1, 3);
plot(A_eig_vec(:, 11:15));

subplot(4, 1, 4);
plot(A_eig_vec(:, 16:20));
```

The result looks like this

[image: Eigen vector plot]

You can see how the eigenvectors seem to capture different frequencies.

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I am looking for. I have 6 matrices corresponding to 6 Poisson's equations (discretization). I would like to see how the eigenvectors change as we change the dimension of the grid. So I need to have everything in one plot, and this is the problem since it is too confusing!

Comment: Hmm... if you generate the matrices with a function, I would recommend adding that code to your question. Playing around with the matrices in question would help think about possible visualizations.